# Riemann integral of $f(x)=2rx$

Tags: riemann-sum, riemann-integration

> Define $$f(x)=
> \begin{cases}2rx,&\text{if }\frac{1}{r+1}<x<=\frac{1}{r}; r=1,2,...\\
> 0,&\text{if } x=0.
> \end{cases}$$
>   Prove that $f$ is Riemann integrable in [0,1] and find integral $f$ from $0$ to $1$.

Since $f$ has countably infinite points of discontinuity but has only one limit point $0$, it is Riemann integrable. Now, here is the confusion, I tried to find the value of integration using upper darboux sum and got answer as $2$ as l.u.b of all the partitions will be $2$ and $U(f,p)=2-1/(n+1)$. Hence after applying limit answer should be $2$ but it is incorrect. Where have I made mistake?

Comment: I think it should say "since $f$ has only a countably infinite number of points of discontinuity" to be more precise.

Comment: @coffeemath yes, I will edit it.

Comment: Answer to this question is pi^2/6

Comment: @Ted Shifrin It goes to infinity right. My bad. I will edit it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this: 
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx = \sum_{r=1}^\infty\int_{1/(r+1)}^{1/r} f(x)\,dx &= \sum_{r=1}^\infty\int_{1/(r+1)}^{1/r} 2rx\,dx = \sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{2r+1}{r(r+1)^2}\\ &= \sum_{r=1}^\infty \left(\frac1{(r+1)^2} + \frac1r - \frac1{r+1}\right).
\end{align*}
Now, it's well known that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac1{n^2} = \dfrac{\pi^2}6$. Can you finish?

Comment: Yes I got this method but I don't know what's the fault in my method. I made n partitions, found out Mi's (l.u.b's) of all partitions and substituted in upper riemann sum and applied limit. Am I making some mistakes there?

Comment: Unless you show me your work, I can't tell you your mistake, but how you got a lower sum to be $2$ is beyond me.  Take the obvious partition $\mathscr P_n = \{0,\frac1n,\frac1{n-1},\dots,\frac12,1\}$, and $L(f,\mathscr P_n) = 2\sum\limits_{k=2}^n\frac1{k^2}$. I get that the upper sums will all be $2$ for this family of partitions. Note that, indeed, $\pi^2/6 < 2$. :)

Comment: In my lessons, I was taught that limit n-> infinity L(f,p) or U(f,p) = integral, so here I applied same logic, so I got 2 as an answer, is it incorrect to apply?

Comment: You have not come close to calculating this correctly. It's virtually impossible to do this problem directly like that.

Comment: Okay thanks. I will apply the method of integration like in this answer for such sums.